# Chang Modal option in active status Bootstrap( v4.1 )

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am facing a problem to change modal `{option}` after it `executed(in show status)` or if it executed once.

It seems like `{options}` value is not affecting if the modal executed once or if the modal active(in show status).

I want to change a `{options}` of bootstrap modal when it activated, or after it executed once.

I need to set the `option` to   `{backdrop:'static'}`

Comment: Please include some code showing what you tried.

Comment: `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/`,   type `$("#exampleModalLive").modal({backdrop:'static', keyboard:false})` in console, you will get a modal which cant be close by esc key and by click other area. but if you open it with $("#exampleModalLive").modal() first time than if you launch 
 your modal with argument, option will affect the modal